# Is it correct to say something / person is suitable for something / person?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Or is better to say:

- something suits *you*
- something is suitable for *you*
- something is suitable for *something else*

And same referring people:

- someone suits *you*
- someone is suitable for *you*
- someone is suitable for *something*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"suits" and "is suitable" actually have slightly different meanings, and the best way to use them in sentences depends on the context.

Generally speaking, "something suits you" and "something is suitable for something else" are the most common structures you will hear.

Some extra detail if you're interested:

"suits" is defined as "be convenient for or acceptable to"

"suitable" is defined as "right or appropriate for a particular person, purpose, or situation"

These are very similar but have slight nuances that are fairly noticeable in actual English.

Generally, "suits" is used as a matter of opinion, whereas "suitable" is used for more factual things and carries less of an opinionated feeling.

It's kind of a hard point to convey, so hopefully these examples help:

"That shirt suits you." = That shirt looks good on you (my opinion).

"That outfit is suitable for the ceremony." = That outfit is appropriate for the ceremony (a formal occasion where one would expect a certain dress code).

"Those boots suit her." = Those boots look good on her.

"Those boots are not suitable." = Those boots are not appropriate in a functional sense (for example, wearing rain boots when mountain climbing).

"That kind of work suits you." = I think that job seems like something you'd like.

"That kind of work is suitable for you." = I think that job fits your skillset.

This is pretty confusing and unfortunately a lot of it is entirely contextual. Of course, just to be a little more confusing (as always in English...), there are some cases where the two are virtually indistinguishable in meaning. In those cases, "suitable" is generally considered marginally more formal and perhaps more appropriate for a business setting.

"What time suits you?" = What time works best for you?

"What time is suitable?" = What time is most appropriate? (which means the exactly the same thing as above, but sounds more formal and carries the overt connotation of setting an appointment)